# How to turn off audio description in windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, audio, accessibility

I am having an issue with a tile that never disappears from my windows machine. This is very annoying since I cannot access the things behind the tile. This has been happening for some days now. **A reboot seems to fix this.** But very often in my day, this reappears.

I am not sure how you can reproduce this problem. This happens when I am on youtube or some video on the internet mostly with Chrome browser

Also, I am in Extend Displays of windows and this shows on my Main Display. I am using two monitors.

Hope this is enough info.

I found this link but this seems to be sth different. https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/turn-on-or-off-audio-description-in-windows-10.html

> The only way to remove this tile is to close the youtube video but reappears when I play a new video.

Take a look at the image below.

[image].

Could someone please provide instructions on how to turn this off?

Comment: Do you have a bluetooth audio device connected with volume control on it? And can you alter the volume without it shooting back to 100%?

Comment: I do not have any Bluetooth devices connected. I do have some headphones though. I did restart my computer. So the problem did go away. I tried playing with changing the volume with the headphones. This did not reproduce the issue.

Comment: Yes this seems to be a windows feature. I managed to replicate it. Although now the notification fades away after some seconds.

Comment: @LPChip - I don't have a media keyboard.

Comment: @panoskarajohn that is what should happen. Next time the notification sticks again, see if changing the volume makes it go away or not. Also keep in mind, the notification will stick if you move the mouse on top.

Comment: Ok copy that. I will update the question if this works